# Проверка на анимированный аватар пользователя дискорд

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
r = Image.open(io.BytesIO(await member.avatar_url.read())).convert('RGBA').resize((228, 229), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

При выводе ранговой карты пользователя мой аватар не анимирован.
Как это можно пофиксить.
**Сохранял и через png и gif**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимированное gif изображение содержит несколько кадров, по-умолчанию Pillow работает только с первым. Пройдись по каждому кадру как по отдельному изображению, обработай, затем обратно сохрани методом `save` с аттрибутами `save_all` и `append_images`.
Подробнее в документации:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#reading-sequences